# automatic configuring of PostgreSQL database with different password

Tags: postgresql

I have recently installed PostgreSQL using PostgreSQL installer in Ubuntu system and configured the location of the database, users manually. Now I would like to install and configure on 3 new systems with different passwords, same database location using the single command line or a Debian package.

If it is JAVA, I can create a deb which just copies the JAVA installation folder and sets JAVA paths. Is something similar possible with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Du you want to copy the database *software* or the database itself?

Comment: database software with different passwords for postgres user

Comment: The operating system user is not part of the software...

Comment: Agree. I will try out and update this thread once I succeed.